# VBA Excel 2010 - Assign unknown chart to varible

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Im trying to set a chart to a varible, however since I have multiple charts in my spreadsheet I need to be able to activate a chart and assign it to a varible.

Ffor the record `ChartHandel = ActiveSheet.ChartObject(1)` doesn't work,I have also tried `.Shape(1)` and `Chart("Name of chart")` and these too dont work

```
Dim ChartHandel2 As Chart

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ChartHandel2 = ActiveChart
```

Even this gets error '91, Object Variable or with block varible not set' which it looks like it should work and I was sure I had had this working at one point(as a workaround)

My question is basicly can you assign a chart to a varible if it isnt active (and if possible how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when assigning object you must use the `Set` keyword in the left part of the assignment statement

furthemore [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx) object is a member of the [ChartObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838184.aspx) object

here's a small example of dealing with them

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartObjects()

Dim chartObj As ChartObject

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("charts")

    For Each chartObj In .ChartObjects

        With chartObj ' to deal with current "ChartObject" object

            With .Chart ' to deal with "Chart" object of "ChartObject" object
                .ChartType = xlXYScatter ' or another XlChartType Enumeration (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838409.aspx)

                MsgBox .ChartArea.Name

                .HasLegend = False

                .ChartTitle.Caption = "chart title you need"
            End With

        End With

    Next chartObj

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my face ... I cant believe I forgot about `set`, just seeing it makes me want to crawl into a deep dark hole

Comment: I am setting this as the answer as im going to use the `Set ChartHandel2 = ActiveChart` for a work around for the moment, the `For Each` loops are a bit beyond me at the moment, if you could provid a link that explains them a bit it would greatly help me

Comment: no need to activate and then set.   you can simply write  "Set ChartHandel2 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)" but remember that "ChartHandel2" must be declared as "ChartObject"

Comment: as for "for each next" its a VBA construct applying to any objects collection. you can see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each to loop through charts if you arent sure with indexes. Something like this

```
Sub testChart()

    Dim testSheet As Worksheet
    Set testSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Dim chartVariable As Chart
    With testSheet
        For Each myChart In .ChartObjects
            Set chartVariable = myChart.Chart

        Next myChart
    End With

End Sub
```

warning: its only demo version, it will need further changes depends on what you need

Comment: Your code works but the changes I need to make for it work the way I need it to are beyond me so I will look into `For Each` loops when I can and hopefully use your code or user3598756 code depending on how it works out, thanks for your answer though